# (Animation) Nodes : how to map a rotation to a value between 0 & 1?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, mathematics

The Parameter input of the Evaluate Spline, in Animation Nodes, needs to get a number between 0 & 1.
I would like to map it to the rotation of an empty (here, Effector-Spline-Loop).
No mather what the Y rotation is, I need to always have a value between 0 & 1.

- 0° -> 0
- 180° -> 0.5
- 360° -> 1
- 540° -> 0.5

How should I improve my nodes ?
Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Map Range Node` is what you are looking for. It takes the input values (min: 0, max: 360) and maps it to the target values (in your case 0 to 1).

Combine that with a `Float Math Node` set to `modulo` of 360. this way you'll only get values between 0 and 360 (540 returns 180 so the map range node will output .5).

separate Euler -> math node -> map range node.

Edit: **final nodetree**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Almost got it.  But can't get it to work with the modulo: it only works between 0 & 360 for now - what am I missing ? https://imgur.com/a/pugBE
PS will it work with negative values too ?

Comment: @gordie Are you putting the "modulo" operation to the right or to the left of the "map range"? If it's to the left, it must be modulo 360, otherwise modulo 1.

Comment: Got it ! https://imgur.com/a/h6pVv Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great. If I'm not mistaking the output of modulo is always positive no matter the input. So it should work just fine.